# How to save echo statement in a variable which consists of javascript confirm box in it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following code

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">confirm("Are You Ready To Restore ?");</script>';
```

Now a confirm box will appears as follows:
[image]

So when user click on ok the process will continue otherwise it will stop further processing as it cancel it.
I want to apply if condition on OK and cancel button . How to save this echo result in variable so that i can apply if condition on it .

Comment: `$var = '<script type="text/javascript">confirm("Are You Ready To Restore ?");</script>';` ???

Comment: confirm returns true or false depending on what user pressed. You can take the return value in a js variable and as @Hanky Panky pointed out, if you want the variable value on PHP side you cannot do it in one http request. You will either have to move the if/else condition to js side or make another http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to save this echo result in variable so that i can apply if condition on it .

You can't do that in one *http request*. You can put Javascript code in your PHP variables, display it but your PHP code will not get the answer to javascript prompt unless you initiate another request, usually via ajax. Or you can take that conditional code to Javascript completely.

PHP is already asleep by the time JavaScript stats working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if condition inside the script
if you click ok it will give you true boolean value or on cancel it will give you false boolean value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = confirm("Are You Ready To Restore ?");
if(x == true){

}else{

}
</script>
```